# Google decreased youtube api v3 limits for queries per day to 10 000 per day for all accounts and projects

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

That's not a yet another question on how to increase quota limits.
Today Google decreased [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) for queries per day from 50 million in my case to 0! Somebody had 1 million queries, 100 000 queries per day, but now everybody have only 10 000 units. It is extremely low, all serious production apps will be suspended soon. That conditions are unacceptable.

This was happened without any notification! No message in cloud console or in mailbox!

That means that we all need to close our projects completely.
Thousands of developers involved with youtube api projects, we wrote lots of code to make all things working, spent a lot of time and power.

And there is no way to solve that problem because Google doesn't give any support with the youtube api. I tried to contact youtube api team with all channels, filled out brand new quota application form ~3 months ago - still no answer or positive changes.

In the official documentation and google cloud console pages written that stackoverflow is the only place where we can get help, because google staff are monitoring tags associated with google services. Maybe this topic aggregate more feedbacks than my previous one  [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79183616)

So I want to ask other developers, what are you going to do with your projects, is 10 000 queries per day enough?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related. SO cant help you with google support issues we recommend you contact Google support.  Sorry even if google says you can get support here we are not google support.

Comment: I would suggest one of two things though:  One its a bug and google will fix it shortly.  Two this is only you and they are blocking your project for making to many requests. 
 On that note none of my projects appear to be turn down.  My quota is still 50,000,000

Comment: I am not alone, I have found the same issue on google tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122273710

Comment: I have created the issue at suggested tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123987186 with my problem, it is still zero limit for queries per day. Maybe somebody else will join the talk. I am happy for you, DalmTo, that your projects continue working.

Comment: @DaImTo I just created a new youtube data v3 app in developer console and its also showing me 10,000 Quota per day limit.

Comment: @Rusty, this is ridiculous, for example, if we want to display a fresh list of videos from our youtube channel, we need to list playlistItems (from uploads playlist), this costs 3 units (URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet). If we have >3000 hits per day, we must cache results or store it in the database and refresh from time to time. So, now we can add a stripped down youtube functionality for some apps, or ask users to generate their own api keys as some TV apps do.

Comment: @ArtemShevtsov I am going through the same situation now. My app got a sudden increase in downloads and it completely depends on Youtube data API. I requested for more usage using their form and got no reply. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Praveena, you can wait for an answer from youtube team (up to three months) or you can start using some unofficial ways of youtube data fetching for your app (download-yt, invidious can be found on github). In my case youtube team decided to reset quota to 0 and blocked my project because the app is not compatible with youtube terms of service =).

Comment: Thank you @ArtemShevtsov

Answer (score -1):

Over the years google has been changing how Quota is applied to new projects.  Orignally (ca 2012) when you created a new project you were always given a quota size of 10000.   This quota was assumed to be a development quota, enough to get your application underdevelopment.  So if we consider this question

> So I want to ask other developers, what are you going to do with your projects, is 10 000 queries per day enough?

The fact is from googles side this was never meant to be your production quota, they always expected you to request more if you needed it.  Some apps dont though I have made serval which just do some monitoring and can use the 10000 quota happily with no issues.

As for your original issue with your quota being reset.  I have seen this a number of times over the years.  People will create new projects and have a quota of 0 from the start.  In that case i always recommend recreating the project.   In the case where you had a large quota and it was reset to a lower value.  This IMO is either a bug on googles side or they spotted an issue with your requests and they want to force you to apply again.  Rude really they could just email you and ask.   There is really no way of knowing the cause because as you said Google does not offer any support contact for YouTube API besides [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)

## update

See this issue [#211012781](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211012781)

> Hi. If you're seeing Queries per day quota set to 0 and the API is indeed enabled, then this means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.

> You should’ve received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain the project’s access. But just in case you missed it, please fill out and submit the exceptions form below:

https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en

Comment: My first projects was launched in 2013 and had 50M quota limit. There was no need to negotiate more quota. And there was no quota application google forms. One thing that was required is to comply with youtube terms of service. For later projects the initial limits have been reduced to 1M (i think is was 2016-2020). In 2021 the initial limit per project was 100 000 units.

Comment: Now in 2022 you get only 10k units for development purposes (which is really uncomfortable and extremely low) and it is really hard to negotiate bigger limits because you should count and explain every query to the api, explain why you need more to youtube team. As the result, they will set up quota limits that they think will be ok for your use case.

Comment: Recently I have launced a new project and made a request through quota application form. I applied for 4M units per day with explanations about what type of queries i am going to make and how much requests i am planning to do, and why. But youtube team decided to give me 1M units per day =)

Comment: when you hit 80% of that quota over serval weeks make a request again.  Things have changed a lot in the last five years.